# Parsing Graphite JSON Response with Gson

Tags: java, gson, graphite

I am writing a Java library for interacting with metrics from Graphite.
A typical JSON response looks like this (taken from the official docs):

```
[{
  "target": "entries",
  "datapoints": [
    [1.0, 1311836008],
    [2.0, 1311836009],
    [3.0, 1311836010],
    [5.0, 1311836011],
    [6.0, 1311836012]
  ]
}]
```

where the first element of the "datapoints" array is the value and the second one the timestamp. I have modelled a GraphiteDataset class as follows

```
class GraphiteDataset {
    private String target;
    private List<GraphiteDatapoint> datapoints;

    ....
}
```

and the GraphiteDatapoint class

```
class GraphiteDatapoint {
    private Long timestamp;
    private Double value;

    ...
}
```

Now I need to parse the response (see above) into the GraphiteDataset
class using Gson. Unfortunately, the elements of "datapoints" are not named objects (e.g. `{timestamp: 1234, value: 1.0}` but a 2 dimensional array so I cannot directly deserialize it into some class. Currently my solution is to have an intermediate class

```
class GraphiteIntermediateDataset {
    private String target;
    private List<String> datapoints;
    ...
}
```

which has the datapoints as Strings and then I parse them into the appropriate GraphiteDatapoint instance. I think that I cannot work around a custom deserializer. Do you have any suggestions or tricks how to make this a little more convenient?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON `[1.2, 123456]` is a array of a `Double` and a `Long`, but they are both `Number`, so try this:

```
class GraphiteDataset {
    private String target;
    private List<List<Number>> datapoints;

    ....
}
```

Then convert `datapoints` into your type after parsing, with something like:

```
List<GraphiteDatapoint> points = datapoints.stream().
    .map(nums -> new GraphiteDatapoint(nums.get(0).doubleValue(), nums.get(1).intValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

assuming a constructor like:

```
class GraphiteDatapoint {
    private Long timestamp;
    private Double value;
    public GraphiteDatapoint(Double value, Long timestamp) {
        this.value = value;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks! I have tried to write a custom deserializer but this solution is much better. My solution now is to keep the intermediate class which has a `List<List<Number>>` instead of `List<GraphiteDatapoint>` but essentially its the same.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution is to introduce an intermediate class `GraphiteIntermediateDataset` which looks as follows:

```
class GraphiteIntermediateDataset {
    private String target;
    private List<List<Number>> datapoints;
}
```

and the deserializer code looks like this

```
List<GraphiteIntermediateDataset> intermediateDatasetList = GSON.fromJson(raw, new TypeToken<List<GraphiteIntermediateDataset>>(){}.getType());

GraphiteIntermediateDataset intermediateDataset = intermediateDatasetList.get(0);

... check if empty (which can happen), when true return an empty GraphiteDataset

List<GraphiteDatapoint> gDatapoints = intermediateDataset
         .stream()
         .map(ds -> {
            return new GraphiteDatapoint(ds.get(0).longValue(),
                                         ds.get(1).doubleValue())
            }
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
return new GraphiteDataset()
       .setDatapoints(gDatapoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type safety and proper data binding are your friends. Gson has several methods to accomplish what you need. For example, declare data transfer objects:

```java
final class GraphiteDataset {

    final String target;

    // The incoming DTO has property `datapoints`, however Java conventions suggest dataPoints (as far as I understand English).
    @SerializedName("datapoints")
    final List<GraphiteDataPoint> dataPoints;

    // Actually, Gson does not need this constructor, and the DTO can even have a single private default one.
    // But in order to make it consistent with the next class just making it programmatically instantiable...
    // Also, but may be opinion-based, hiding constructors is really a good idea since one can hide the instantiation strategy whilst constructors cannot.
    private GraphiteDataset(final String target, final List<GraphiteDataPoint> dataPoints) {
        this.target = target;
        this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    }

}
```

```java
final class GraphiteDataPoint {

    final double value;
    final long timestamp;

    private GraphiteDataPoint(final double value, final long timestamp) {
        this.value = value;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    // Instantiation must be accessible programmatically somehow
    static GraphiteDataPoint graphiteDataPoint(final double value, final long timestamp) {
        return new GraphiteDataPoint(value, timestamp);
    }

}
```

And then implement either a GraphiteDataPoint JSON deserializer:

```java
// In Gson serializers and deserializers can only deal with intermediate Gson JSON tree representation of objects (JsonElement-s).
// For some cases it's quite simple, if the given data to serialize/deserialize does not consume much memory
final class GraphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<GraphiteDataPoint> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<GraphiteDataPoint> graphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer = new GraphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer();

    private GraphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    // Not letting to instantiate a stateless (so it's thread-safe) deserializer twice or more
    static JsonDeserializer<GraphiteDataPoint> getGraphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer() {
        return graphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphiteDataPoint deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonArray asJsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        final double value = asJsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsDouble();
        final long timestamp = asJsonArray.get(1).getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong();
        return graphiteDataPoint(value, timestamp);
    }

}
```

Or a type adapter:

```java
// Type adapters, unlike serializers and deserializers, are designed to work with streams.
// They may look too low-level and tedious/hard to implement, but for some cases they can be useful in both serialization and deserialization.
// For the case #1: no need to serialize nested objects recursively to transform them to JSON trees that can be important for large objects.
// For the case #2: intermediate JSON trees are not necessary (but internal buffers are).
final class GraphiteDataPointTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<GraphiteDataPoint> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<GraphiteDataPoint> graphiteDataPointTypeAdapter = new GraphiteDataPointTypeAdapter();

    private GraphiteDataPointTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<GraphiteDataPoint> getGraphiteDataPointTypeAdapter() {
        return graphiteDataPointTypeAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final GraphiteDataPoint value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public GraphiteDataPoint read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        in.beginArray();
        final double value = in.nextDouble();
        final long timestamp = in.nextLong();
        in.endArray();
        return graphiteDataPoint(value, timestamp);
    }

}
```

Both implementations are essentially the same, but may be crucial for you dependening on data (de)serialization strategies and costs. Example use:

```java
private static final String JSON = "[{\"target\":\"entries\",\"datapoints\":[[1.0,1311836008],[2.0,1311836009],[3.0,1311836010],[5.0,1311836011],[6.0,1311836012]]}]";

// Gson is thread-safe and can be shared between threads, so no need to instantiate it every time it's needed
private static final Gson gsonWithDeserializers = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(GraphiteDataPoint.class, getGraphiteDataPointJsonDeserializer())
        .create();

private static final Gson gsonWithTypeAdapters = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(GraphiteDataPoint.class, getGraphiteDataPointTypeAdapter())
        .create();

private static final TypeToken<List<GraphiteDataset>> graphiteDatasetsTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<GraphiteDataset>>() {
};

public static void main(final String... args) {
    dumpGraphiteDatasets(gsonWithDeserializers.fromJson(JSON, graphiteDatasetsTypeToken.getType()));
    dumpGraphiteDatasets(gsonWithTypeAdapters.fromJson(JSON, graphiteDatasetsTypeToken.getType()));
}

private static void dumpGraphiteDatasets(final Iterable<GraphiteDataset> graphiteDatasets) {
    graphiteDatasets.forEach(graphiteDataset -> {
        out.println(graphiteDataset.target);
        graphiteDataset.dataPoints.forEach(graphiteDataPoint -> {
            out.print("  ");
            out.print(graphiteDataPoint.value);
            out.print(" ");
            out.println(graphiteDataPoint.timestamp);
        });
    });
}
```

The output:

```
entries
  1.0 1311836008
  2.0 1311836009
  3.0 1311836010
  5.0 1311836011
  6.0 1311836012
entries
  1.0 1311836008
  2.0 1311836009
  3.0 1311836010
  5.0 1311836011
  6.0 1311836012
```